# neo4j Similarity cosine graphaware

Tags: plugins, neo4j, graphaware

How do i write a statement for similarity cosine using `ga.nlp.ml.similarity.cosine` for node `News`:

> ```
> CREATE (n:News)
> SET n.text = "Scores of people were already lying dead or injured inside a crowded Orlando nightclub,
> and the police had spent hours trying to connect with the gunman and end the situation without further violence.
> But when Omar Mateen threatened to set off explosives, the police decided to act, and pushed their way through a
> wall to end the bloody standoff.";
> ```

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: you need at least two nodes/news to compute similarity between objects. Could you refine your requirements?

Comment: yes i know that it requires 2 nodes.
i have 2 nodes but i need to know the proper syntax with an example.
Because when am trying to run it i am facing with some errors like :

"Type mismatch: expected List<Node> but was Boolean (line 3, column 35 (offset: 72)) "CALL ga.nlp.ml.similarity.cosine(n:News,5,n1.people,n1.HAS_TAG) YIELD result return result""

I need some examples because all the reference for similarity cosine is outdated . No new uploaded details, so i require an example to continue it.

Comment: Type mismatch: expected List<Node> but was Map (line 3, column 34 (offset: 71))
"CALL ga.nlp.ml.similarity.cosine({a:n.text,n:n.id},5,n.people,n.HAS_TAG) YIELD result return result"

Answer (score 4):

This is the call structure:

```
CALL ga.nlp.ml.similarity.cosine([<nodes>],depth,Query,Relationship type)
//nodes->The list of annotated nodes for which it will compute the distances
//depth->Integer. if 0, it will not use Concept Net 5 imported data for the distance computing. If greater than 0 it will consider concepts during computation, the value will define how much in general it should go.
//Query->String. It is the query that will be used to compute the tags vector, some are already defined, so this cold be null
//Relationship Type->String. The name to assign to the Relationship created between AnnotatedText nodes.
```

This is an example:

```
MATCH (a:AnnotatedText) 
with collect(a) as list
CALL ga.nlp.ml.similarity.cosine(list, 0, null, "SIMILARITY") YIELD result
return result
```

Comment: When I try with the same example i get result 2.
But what does it mean?
Bcz i read if its 1 den its similar
if its -1 den its dissimilar

Comment: Did you check if the new relationship has been created?

Answer (score 0):

```
     CALL ga.nlp.ml.similarity.cosine([<nodes>],depth,Query,Relationship type)
//nodes->Must be annotated nodes
//depth->integer data
//Query->String
//Relationship Type->String
```